# pass an ID with hyperlik but cant get this ID value from a fk in one table when i click in insert

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, conflict

Something strange happened in my codes, actually I have a hyperlink that pass ID value in a query string to second page.in second page i have 2 sql datasource that both these sql datasources  should get this id value  and pass it to a filter parameter to show sth in datalist.

so in another word I have a first page that has an hyperlink read ID value from a datasource and pass it to second page.its like below:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# "~/forumpage.aspx?ID="+Eval("ID")%>'><%#Eval("title")%> </asp:HyperLink>
```

then in second page i have one sql datasource with a query like this ...where ID=@id and get this id in  query string from db.it work great . but i have problem with second sql datasource in second page it has a query sth like below:...forms.question_id=@id
then in sql reference both to query string as ID that get by first  page in hyperlink.
but when i click in insert button show me error with fk.

> error:Error:The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY
>   constraint "FK_forumreply_forumquestions". The conflict occurred in
>   database "forum", table "dbo.forumquestions", column 'ID'. The
>   statement has been terminated.

my tables

1. (question(ID,user_id(fk),Cat_id(fk),title,bodytext)
2. (reply(ID,userr_id(fk),questionn_id(fk),titlereply,bodytestreply);

When by hand in cb i gave a number in questionn_id like 1 it show me successful but when  it want read from a filter by datasource this field face with problem.

plzzzz help i really need skip from this part.and cause i am new i guess I cant understand the logic way clearly.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sdsreply" runat="server" 
                    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:forumConnectionString %>" 
                    SelectCommand="SELECT forumreply.ID, forumreply.userr_id, forumreply.questionn_id, forumreply.bodytextreply, forumreply.datetimereply, forumquestions.ID AS Expr1, forumusers.ID AS Expr2, forumusers.username FROM forumquestions INNER JOIN forumreply ON forumquestions.ID = forumreply.questionn_id INNER JOIN forumusers ON forumquestions.user_id = forumusers.ID AND forumreply.userr_id = forumusers.ID where forumreply.questionn_id=@questionn_id">
                    <SelectParameters>
                        <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="questionn_id" QueryStringField="ID" />
                    </SelectParameters>
                </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

it is cb for second page in insert button:

```
    {
        if (Session["userid"] != null)
        {

            lblreply.Text = Session["userid"].ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            Session["userid"]=null;

        }

        if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {

            lblshow.Text = string.Empty;


                string d = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
                lblshow.Text =d + "عزیز خوش آمدید." ;

                foreach (DataListItem item in DataList2.Items)
                {
                    Label questionn_idLabel = (Label)item.FindControl("questionn_idLabel");
                    Label userr_idLabel = (Label)item.FindControl("userr_idLabel");
                    lbltest.Text = string.Empty;
                    lbltest.Text = questionn_idLabel.Text;
                    lblreply.Text = string.Empty;
                    lblreply.Text = userr_idLabel.Text;

                }


        }
        else
        {
            lblshow.Text = "اگر بار اول هست که می خواهید پاسخ دهید لطفا ابتدا  ثبت نام و سپس لاگین فرمائید.";
        }
    }



    {
        if(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            if (Page.IsValid)
            {





                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["forumConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
                try
                {
                    con.Open();


                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into forumreply    (userr_id,questionn_id,bodytextreply,datetimereply)values(@userr_id,@questionn_id,@bodytextreply,@datetimereply)", con);

                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("userr_id",lblreply.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("questionn_id",lbltest.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("bodytextreply",txtbody.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("datetimereply",DateTime.Now );
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


                }
                catch (Exception exp)
                {
                    Response.Write("<b>Error:</b>");
                    Response.Write(exp.Message);
                }
                finally
                {
                    con.Close();
                }







                lblmsg.Text = "پیام شما با موفقیت ثبت گردید.thx";
                lblshow.Visible = false;

                //lbltxt.Text = txtbody.Text;
                txtbody.Text = string.Empty;

            }





        }
        else 
        {
            lblmsg.Text = string.Empty;
            Session["rem"] = Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri;
            Response.Redirect("~/login.aspx");



        }

    }
```

Comment: calm down ! we need to look into the problem first

Comment: The error mentions an INSERT. The code you posted does not. Are you missing some code?

Comment: The `INSERT` statement does not match your table definition. Which of the two tables you specified would be `forumreply`? You'll need to make sure the columns of the INSERT statement match whatever is in the table.

Comment: you have a foreign key contraint in your DB ... FK_forumreply_forumquestions ... this constraint forced the INSERT to fail ... the problem has nothing to do with **reading** from the tables ... check that constraint ... on the foreign side you probably tried to insert a key that was not present on the primary side

Comment: in insert button when i writecmd.paramaters.addwithvalue("questionn_id","1") a number like 1 it work good and insert but when i want read this field from a datalist row that cover with eval(question_id) and put it in a label it show me error.i just have problem with this  fk problems.it cant read from datalist control.

Comment: yes exatly dark.i guess my code have np..all has problem is that with this fk that u named above..ok i would check.